# Locking one blog of many in a multi user/blog Wordpress installation

Tags: multisite, database, network-admin

I have a multi user /wordpress installation that is working fine. One of the blogs running on that multi user /wordpress installation will never be updated again but I want it there for historic reasons.

Is it possible to make one blog read-only even though it is on a multi user /wordpress installation and sharing a database with the other blogs?

**Edit**
To make it clear; I want to freeze the entire blog including contents and users. I have implemented the suggestions given for the blog I am currently asking about since it only has 1 user, but I wish not having to delete users at a later time on other blogs i administer since then their names and timestamps would disappear from the site which is not what I want.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your user account structure. The superadmin of the MU can always edit anything and you cannot lock that one out for obvious reasons, but you can remove all other users from that 1 website you want to lock down.

Go to Network Admin > Sites > Edit (link) and then in the Users TAB you can remove all users except the network superadmin.

If you want to lock it for external users, just turn off user registration and comments for that site.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have done as you wrote to make the blog go more towards a read-only site for both previous users of the blog but also external users.